# How to add mean for each record of the same category in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I will use to train a model, and I wish to add a new feature in order to get rid of a categorical feature.

I have a column zip_reg which is categorical that contains around 106 different value, my data set has around 150k record, on the other hand I have a numerical feature "amount" which I wish to compute the mean for each record of the same class, here's an example:

```
zip_reg     amount
A           100
B           200
B           100
C           100
C           150
C           150
```

For the class A, we have a mean of 100, for class B we have a mean of (300/2 = 150) and for class C we have a mean of 200, I wish to add a new column mean_amount to put the mean amount of each record from the same category, ie:

```
zip_reg     amount    mean_amount
A           100       100
B           200       150
B           100       150
C           100       200
C           150       200
C           150       200
```

I used `groupby.mean()` to get the mean of each class but how can I add the column so that each entry would the mean value of its class in an elegant way without writing a whole function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with `mean`

```
df['mean_amount'] = df.groupby('zip_reg')['amount'].transform('mean')

print (df)
  zip_reg  amount  mean_amount
0       A     100   100.000000
1       B     200   150.000000
2       B     100   150.000000
3       C     100   133.333333
4       C     150   133.333333
5       C     150   133.333333
```